# How to kill a process that autostarts

Tags: 18.04, cpu, process, kill

Recently I started managing a server (hostsed by a cloud provider) for my work. Problem is that the server is injected.
Within now and a few months the server will be replaced by a new one in order to solve any threads.

THE QUESTION:
In the ubuntu server there is a process I cannot totally backtrack the origin from which is coming back regularly. The process is using ca 80% of all available CPU will come back after being killed. Is there a way to automaticly kill that process when it comes up (always has the same name). Or is there a way to block that process from starting up (process is not listed in startup scripts).

Maybe this question is really dumb or incomplete. Skill set with this is not the greatest. So any advice/tips are welcome.

The process name is called kthzabor and the ubuntu version is 18.04

Comment: might help to know what the process is and the version of ubuntu as a start. [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Will update the question ! Thanks for the feadback

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys ! Just checked crontab on all users but no crons could be found.

Also tried an locate kthzabor but it just returned a new terminal line (no results).

Will install sysdig ! that is a nice tip. Will update you with those results

Comment: Here the update ! I found the location of the file :D. It was placed in /dev/shm.
I delete the file but as expected the issue lays way deeper :0. I now made a script with incron that removes the file everytime it shows up.

It probably is not the most cleanest solution but we will be migrating away from this server.

@Rinzwind can you post ur answer to this question beceause that is the way of how I found the issue !

Comment: I added some extra's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- kthzabor is a crypyo miner.

Use the following commands to see if you can find the offending file:

```
sudo -i && crontab -l 
crontab -l 
more /etc/crontab 
grep kthzabor /etc/systemd/system/*
sudo updatedb && locate kthzabor
```

and see if that shows anything.

If those do not you can also do a

```
sudo find / -name '*kthzabor*' -print
```

but this will take a while :)

Another one that will help:

```
pstree -aH {pid of the process to find}
```

This will list all processes with commands

This time it was located in `/dev/shm` so to anyone reading this check that one 1st.

Just dealing the offending script is the 1st step: the script will be recreated when removed. Do a `sudo chmod 000 kthzabor` and it will be unreadable, and undeletable. That might stop it. Might be better than removing it.

[sysdig](https://sysdig.com/) is a tool to trace a process back to what started it. There will be a process active that you need to delete/inactivate. Just removing the offending script is the 1st step.